Add a transform filter to lookup data in altair chart
How do I add a filter to a lookup dataset?
I am following the the Connections chart: https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/airport_connections.html. I generated a dataset similar to the two datasets used (airports and flights_airport).
My data differs in that I added a "region" where the point (airport) would fall into. I then added a third dataset that iterates through a set number of clusters and predicts the region of the point using a KMeans model. I want to set the color of the points to the color of the predicted region from the KMeans model. I can do this by hardcoding a filter into the dataframe but ultimately I would like to have the filter built into the altair chart and not hardcoded.
# Make blobs
n = 50
x, y = make_blobs(n, 2, centers=4, random_state=42, cluster_std=2)

# Frame it
airports = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['latitude', 'longitude'])
iata = np.array([i for i in range(n)]).reshape(-1,1)
airports['iata'] = iata
airports['region'] = y
airports = airports[['iata', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'region']]

# Find variable
data = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        if i != j:
            data.append([i, j, np.random.randint(1, 100)])

# Frame it
flights_airport = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['origin', 'destination', 'routes'])

# Apply K-means clustering
for num_clusters in range(1, n):

    # Create KMeans clustering model and fit to airport data
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)
    kmeans.fit(airports[['latitude', 'longitude']])

    # Concatenate to "data" for the clusters dataframe
    if num_clusters == 1:
        data = np.concatenate([iata, np.array([num_clusters]*n).reshape(-1,1), kmeans.labels_.reshape(-1,1)], axis=1)
    else:
        new_data = np.concatenate([iata, np.array([num_clusters]*n).reshape(-1,1), kmeans.labels_.reshape(-1,1)], axis=1)
        data = np.concatenate([data, new_data], axis=0)

# Create clusters dataframe
clusters = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['iata', 'number_clusters', 'predicted region'])

# I want to add this filter in my altair chart
#clusters = clusters[clusters['number_clusters']==4]

# Create selection (select the point (airport))
select_city = alt.selection_point(
    on='click', nearest=True, fields=['origin'], empty=False
)

# Create lookups for points and clusters
airports_lookup = alt.LookupData(
    airports, key='iata', fields=['latitude', 'longitude', 'region']
)
cluster_lookup = alt.LookupData(
    clusters, key='iata', fields=['number_clusters', 'predicted region']
)

# Create a dropdown to filter clusters by the number of clusters
num_clusters_downdrop = alt.binding_select(options=[str(i+1) for i in range(50)], name='Number of Clusters')
downdrop_select = alt.selection_point(fields=['number_clusters'], bind=num_clusters_downdrop)

# Create the connections
connections = alt.Chart(flights_airport).mark_rule(opacity=0.35).encode(
    latitude='latitude:Q',
    longitude='longitude:Q',
    latitude2='lat2:Q',
    longitude2='lon2:Q'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='origin',
    from_=airports_lookup
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='destination',
    from_=airports_lookup, 
    as_=['lat2', 'lon2', 'Blob']
).transform_filter(
    select_city
)

# Create points chart to show the points (airports)
points = alt.Chart(flights_airport).mark_circle().encode(
    latitude='latitude:Q', 
    longitude='longitude:Q',
    color='predicted region:N'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='origin', 
    from_=airports_lookup
).transform_lookup(
    # Look up the 'predicted region' based on origin
    lookup='origin', 
    from_=cluster_lookup
).add_params(
    select_city
).add_params(
    downdrop_select
)

connections + points

